# Ebean - Which find to use for multiple results?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play Framework and thus Ebean, I need to find the information inside the 'value' column by searching for the 'company_id'. However, There will be multiple rows with the same company_id and i need to find all of them and put them in a list (doesn't have to be a list, but would make the most sense).

My Table looks like this:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | company_id | parent_id |   value   |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |          1 |         0 | Group1    |
|  2 |          1 |         1 | SubGroup1 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

And my code like this :

```
@Entity
public class Groups extends Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public long id;

    public Long company_id;

    public Long parent_id;

    public String value;


    public static final Finder<Long, Groups> find = new Finder<Long,Groups>(Long.class, Groups.class);

    public static Groups findByCompanyId(Long id){
        return find.where().eq("company_id", id).findUnique();
    }
```

Obviously, .findunique(); wont work as it is not unique, what should i be using? And should my String *value* remain a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebean provides a method `findList()` which returns a `List`.

I think this should give you the desired result:

```
public static List<Groups> findByCompanyId(Long id){
    return find.where().eq("company_id", id).findList();
}
```

I am unsure what your `value` column holds. If it's an ID of a group you can change the type to `Groups`. But this will require recursive queries which Ebean does not support via its API, you will have to write raw SQL for that. If you want to avoid these recursive queries you need to get all groups via Ebean and filter them in Java.